# Compile a library aiming to reduce size as much as possible

Tags: compiling, gcc, dynamic-linking, optimization

I have to 'squeeze' all the needed code to run ldaps on an embedded system. So the 3 MiB of lybcrypto and almost 700KiB of libssl are way too much.

I'm now experimenting on ldapsearch because reading from ldap is the most important goal.

I've checked with `ld ldapsearch` which shared objects are used by ldapsearch and i found this:

```
670K /usr/local/lib64/libssl.so.1.1    **
3,3M /usr/local/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1 **
 40K  /usr/lib64/libcrypt.so.1 -> libcrypt-2.17.so
104K /usr/lib64/libresolv.so.2 -> libresolv-2.17.so
2,1M /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.17.so **
 19K /usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 -> libdl-2.17.so
139K /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.17.so
 12K  usr/lib64/libfreebl3.so
```

so the ones marked `**` are the most critical

Now I have absolutely no idea how to compile this stuff starting from downloaded source and what command should I give to gcc to compile optimizing size.

I also taught if it would give space save to static-link the shared-object. (I think, based on what I read, optimizer in this case could strip most of unused code while linking as so all the entry point would be compiled anyway)

I found the optimization I could try first is `-Os`, I put it into `cflags` and `lib_cflags` string in `Configurations/00-base-templates.conf` but size is still the same

EDIT
Another option I was suggested is to use `strip`, but I don't know how to give it to `.\config`

Comment: Please tell some details about your embedded system (processor, memory, OS, ...) If you have more than one program that needs to handle SSL connections it will probably increase the total size when you use static libraries. I guess you need special library versions optimized for space like uClibc-ng and maybe an environment to create the base system for your embedded device, e.g `buildroot`, `yocto` or `ptxdist`.

Comment: Actually the target is a PPC with 10 MiB flash memory and a custom linux. By now, ldap is the only service that will require openssl. Now I'm tasked to find out if it's viable to deploy ldaps on that system. Currently the data that will be distributed via ldap are updated by-hand on each and every device.

Comment: @Please add all clarification to the question. How do you create the custom Linux? Does this system allow to use alternative libraries? Maybe you can replace openssl with a different library. A search for "openssl embedded" led me to "wolfssl", which seems to be used in openembedded, see https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layers/

Comment: 1> I did not created the custom *nix (it's a product internal to our company) 2> I can use other libs but those must be certified for safety

Comment: You don't necessarily need to add `strip` to the config file. It can be called as a command on the compiled `.so` file.  You could try it by copying one of the pre-compiled .so files (eg `/usr/local/lib64/libssl.so.1.1`) and running strip on the copy.  See the user manual: https://linux.die.net/man/1/strip

Comment: @PhilipCouling thank you, the so losses about 400K out of 3,3MiB